# How do I hide controls and cause others to shift place in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, controls

I'm programming an app for iOS 7 in Xcode 5.

1. I have three text boxes at the top of my page, each right above the other. Let's call them topTextBox, middleTextBox, and bottomTextBox.
2. My intent is that depending on a particular condition, the topTextBox might not be visible (or present, really) when the view loads.
3. If topTextBox isn't present (or hidden, or whatever) I would like middleTextBox and bottomTextBox to be placed further up the page...as if topTextBox wasn't ever there in the first place (so middleTextBox is in the spot topTextBox used to be in, and bottomTextBox is in the spot middleTextBox was in).

I'm using storyboards with AutoLayout ON. I can't seem to figure out what to do with the constraints for each of the three textBoxes to make this work. Making middleTextBox and bottomTextBox sit higher on the page when topTextBox is hidden doesn't need to be dynamic--I make the decision to show or not show topTextBox in ViewDidLoad()--I just need to get them to show up in the right place depending on my conditions.

Questions:

a. Is making topTextBox.hidden = YES the right way to get topTextBox to not be shown? Or is there some way to make it not noticed by the view at all?

b. What do I do with these constraints on middleTextBox and bottomTextBox to move them up on the page in this condition?

c. Is there anything else I should know to get this to work that I'm not thinking of? Perhaps a better method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just hard coding the frame logic? This could be very effective. All you have to do is conditionally populate an array containing pointers to your text fields and then perform a little frame arithmetic on their y origins. For example, this could easily display all the fields:

```
NSArray *fields = @[topTextField, middleTextField, bottomTextField];


for (int i = 0 ; i < fields.count ; i ++) {

    UITextField *field = fields[i];
    [field setFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 20.0 + (i * 50.0), 280.0, 34.0)];

}
```

Produces this:

[image]

Or at its most basic level, something like this could be used to check whether any of the text fields should/shouldn't be shown, and either hides them, or adjusts their frame accordingly.

```
BOOL shouldShowTop = YES;
BOOL shouldShowMiddle = NO;
BOOL shouldShowBottom = YES;


NSMutableArray *fields = [NSMutableArray new];

if (shouldShowTop) {
    [fields addObject:topTextField];
}else{
    [topTextField setHidden:YES];
}

if (shouldShowMiddle) {
    [fields addObject:middleTextField];
}else{
    [middleTextField setHidden:YES];
}

if (shouldShowBottom) {
    [fields addObject:bottomTextField];
}else{
    [bottomTextField setHidden:YES];
}

for (int i = 0 ; i < fields.count ; i ++) {

    UITextField *field = fields[i];
    [field setFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 20.0 + (i * 50.0), 280.0, 34.0)];

}
```

Will produce this:

[image]

Comment: I'll look at this in more detail and see how viable it is for my app.  If it's really this much coding, I'm tempted to just build two completely separate views (with/without the fields I need) and swap them in/out depending on the condition.  But thanks for the food for thought!

Comment: @Kent Don't be afraid to dig in an write a bunch of code. You aren't  anywhere as limited as your are with Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the height of `topTextField` so that it has zero height could also work for you.

```
   CGRect  frame = topTextField.frame;
   frame.size.height =0;
   topTextField.frame = frame;
```

This is a good choice should you want to animate its re-appearance later on.

As for constraints, constrain the top of the `topTextField` to the superview,  and then the top of `middleTextField` and `bottomTextField` to the bottom of the textfield above.

Do *not* set a constraint for the height of `topTextField`, but do set width constraints.   You'll need to set the height of `topTextField` in `viewDidLoad:`

Comment: This looks simple and promising, but .frame.height and .frame.size.height both give build errors (not assignable).  I've also tried this `CGRect frameRect = self.eventName.frame;
    frameRect.size.height = 0;
    self.eventName.frame = frameRect;` and then adding this: `self.eventName.hidden = YES;` and none of these options actually make the text box disappear (other than the hidden code) but in no case does everything shift upwards on the page according to the constraints (I rebuilt them very simply as directed). Not sure why it's still not working. Note:eventName is the real topTextBox.

Comment: My bad: the individual members of the CGRect structure are immutable.   Answer edited accordingly.  As to the not working: What other constraints are present?   Try investigating this with [UIView onstraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:] ([see](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ResolvingIssues/ResolvingIssues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH17-SW1)).

Answer (score 0):

Setting the height constraint of topTextField to 0 will help you to achieve this.
provided all textfields are connected through vertical space constraint